# jQuery draggable goes out of it's parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have found a really annoying bug which i can't fix.

Basically if I have a div with fixed width and height and then if I would add one more element to that div content with *higher* width it would cause a bug where draggable element goes out of its containing element.

I have created a jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/55rrq/)

To make this bug happen simply drag draggable div to the right side of container and then try dragging it out the container again and it will go out by around 10px, if the process is repeated it can go out as much as you want.

One way I found to if it is by adding overflow hidden to the draggable element, but in my case I need content to be visible no matter what.

**JS:**

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    containment: "parent"
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:400px;
    height: 400px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#draggable{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}

.footer{
    width: 120%;
    height :10px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Note that this bug does not appear in FF (20)

Comment: Your best bet would be to somehow consider the overflowing size in the drag operation, i.e. in the size of some wrapper around `#draggable`. Haven't found an automatic way though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to do this manually

first add the drag `start` event and compare

```
if($('.container').position.left+$('.container').width ==
$('.draggable').position.left+$('.draggable').width{
event.preventDefault();  //cancel the drag.
//reset the position of draggable to 1 less then the current
$('#draggable').css('left',$('#draggable').css('left')-3);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `.css`, use `.position().left` and `.width`. They automatically omit the `px`.

Comment: Documentation for `.position`: http://api.jquery.com/position/ Even the example shows that there is no `px`... Documentation for `.width`: http://api.jquery.com/width/ Quote: `The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400)...` Your argument is invalid.

Comment: yes. you are right... i'm making a fiddle now. i'll edit it later

Comment: But by stopping drag event once draggable element is over the borders i can't drag element back take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/55rrq/3/

Comment: can you post the jsbin.com link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Derija93/55rrq/4/ I guess the static numbers have to do with borders...

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as Linas. Once you run `event.prevenDefault();`, you lose the drag. So you must re-click the element to drag it. Anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The width[120%] of footer suggests that it will always exceed 20% than its parent's width.

As you do not want overflow to be hidden, This can be done by either fixing the size of the footer [in pixels] or by keeping it @ 100% or less.

Comment: Well if it was that simple i wouldn't be posting here. And this is just an example, the real problem is a lot more complicated where more elements needs to outside draggable element borders, so your sugguestions will not work.

Comment: @janak answered correct for the problem you posted here +1. If your real problem is different please post that.

Comment: @eka So what both of you are saying that it's impossible to have content wider then draggable element width? Because this is the problem, i need it to be wider.

Comment: I don't think it's the solution to the problem posted here. The problem clearly says that the content width in some cases must be longer than the draggable element, but this answer proposes to bind the content to a maximum width... not the solution to *this* problem.